# Can there be a Two Nakshatra on Same Day?

Tags: nakshatra, kundali

How Can we Calculate Birth Nakshatra ?

Is it calculated on below things :

1. Date and timings of person ?
2. Kundli of Person ?
3. Place of Birth ?

Because When We checked with Astrologers, One Astrologer Said it is Jyesta & another said it is Anuradha. I want to know how they calculated ?

DOB : 28/04/1994 , Time : 12 : 34 PM , Place of Birth : Bengaluru

Are there 2 different panchangas ? So in one Panchang ( Normal ) , it show jyesta and in another ( Tadguna - specially for marriage related ) it is Anuradha.

Comment: You yourself can find out the Janma Nakshtra by putting DOB and POB here - https://www.drikpanchang.com/jyotisha/kundali/janma-kundali.html

Comment: In the question you have given date of birth and time of birth but place of birth is also needed for casting the horoscope.

Comment: @Rickross i have updated the question with `place of birth`

Comment: Those details give Jyeshtha as the Nakshtra not Anuradha.

Comment: @Rickross Thankyou,  so can girl [ rakshasa guna ] & boy [ manushya gana ] can marry ? can you please guide me ?

Comment: You can use the following site to get the match making https://www.astrosage.com/freechart/matchmaking.asp

Comment: Or this one -- https://www.mpanchang.com/astrology/nakshatra-matching/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The birth Nakshatra is simply the Nakshatra that the moon is in at the time of birth. Location on earth doesn't really affect this much. Location primarily affects the Lagna as it's the Raashi that is rising on the eastern horizon (the eastern horizon changes with location at any given time).

The 27 Nakshatras and the 12 raashis are simply a division of the 360 degree sky  in 27 and 12 parts respectively. This division is of the stars (other than Surya). Since the stars are so far away, the Grahas appear to move through these 27/12 divisions.

When the moon is in a certain division, it is said that the moon is in X raashi and X Nakshatra. A Raashi contains 30degrees of the 360 total, and a Nakshatra contains 13degrees and 20 minutes (aka 13.33 degrees).

Now, can there be two Nakshatras in one 24h day? Absolutely, since the moon can transition from one of the 1/27 (of the whole sky) division to another in a day. So, the time of birth does affect it, even one hour here and there can change the Nakshatra if the divisions are close enough.

Now, there's a thing called precession of the equinoxes. Basically the earth, along with a rotation on the axis every 24 hours, has another rotation related to the axis. This rotation involves the rotation of the axis itself, which takes approximately 24 thousand years per cycle. Since Jyotisham is extremely old (several thousand years at the very least), the position of stars in the sky now are different to what they were 2 thousand years ago.

This throws out of whack the astronomical calculations with the observed reality and must be corrected to have an accurate horoscope.

However, thankfully, since Jyotisham is provided to us by Lord Brahmaa, Shri Surya and the great Rshis like Paraashara Maharishi, Jaimini Maharishi et al., there's a solution to this issue in astronomical texts like Surya Siddhanta and others. Using this, you can add a correction to the formulas.

Because the stars, relative to each other are roughly in the same position, as long as you know the boundaries of each division, you can simply add the formulas, and correct everything.

But... this is where the real problem comes in, no one definitively knows where one division ends and starts. People know what stars are in what division (due to their descriptions in relation to other stars), but people don't know if the Raashi starts 10degrees before that star, or 9 or 11. This creates a slight error. This correction containing errors is controlled by something called as an Ayanamsha. Multiple Ayanamshas propose multiple different degrees for the starting of a Raashi/Nakshatra. These, typically differ by 1-2 degrees at most, with each other. It doesn't matter too much in the main Kshetra Chakra (or what you call as 'Raashi chart'), but it does lead to huge errors in the Varga Chakras like Navamsha among others.

Now, depending on which Ayanamsha you use, the Nakshatra of the moon (and other Grahas) can be different simply because the starting/ending point of a Nakshatra changes depending on the Ayanamsha in use.

Which Ayanamsha is correct? No one knows for sure, I've found the one used by the majority of Jyotishis in India is wrong. It's called the Lahiri Ayanamsha. The correct one is Pushya Paksha Ayanamsha.

---

Now, as for your actual question.

Your birth time happens to be in that border situation, where a change in the definition for the beginning of a Nakshatra, changes the position of the Graha, in this case, Chandra.

One of the Jyotishis you saw, is using the wrong Ayanamsha (not Lahiri), and the other is using something close to the correct Pushya Paksha Ayanamsha like Surya Siddhanta Ayanamsha, for example.

I checked your dates, and your Chandra Nakshatra at time of birth is indeed Jyeshthaa Prathama Pada and not Anuraadhaa Chaturtha pada.

Even Lahiri, in your case produces Jyeshthaa and not something else. It's likely that the person you saw is using something made a few hundred years ago which hasn't had a correction in all that time, or, the correction that is made is completely out of whack due to the very wrong Ayanamsha (which is somehow even worse than the Lahiri one).

Comment: thankyou, so can girl [ rakshasa guna - jyesta , vristika ] & boy [ manushya gana - taurus , rohini ] can marry ? can you please guide me ?

Comment: @USer345738380 It's not that simple, the D-9, D-16, D-1, D-12, D-30 and D-27, along with Janma Nakshatra, Janma Vaara, Janma Tithi, Janma Yoga, Janma Karana, Kaaraka tithi, Kaaraka Yoga, Time of birth, nature and past history of both individuals, shadbala, ashtakavarga, Mahaa and Antar Dashaa, position of all Grahas and Upagrahas in Raashis/Nakshatras and Bhaavas, Kaala chakra, Kota Chakra, Sudarshana Chakra, Harsha bala, Vimshopakabala, Ishtaphala Bala, Yogas and many other things like Muhurata as well need to be considered. It's best you find a Jyotishi who you can interact with personally.

Comment: boy : Vikas , 22/03/1991 ,  5:35 am ,  bhadravathi . Girl :  nayana , 28/04/1994 , 12: 34 pm  bengaluru . i know this is not correct to ask here. we checked with many astrologers and it's  50 : 50 . can you please check and guide me on this ?

Comment: @USer345738380 I don't have sufficient experience, neither is it a good use of my time to do what you're asking. More importantly, it won't be fair to you as I don't know the temperaments and characteristics of the both of you (which is important). Moreover, I don't have certainty of the birth time. To make sure it is correct, as far as the Navamsha and Shastyamsha goes, your birth time needs to be around a minute or two within the actual time. To make sure this is correct, requires semi-extensive knowledge of the past events in the life of both of you. I hope you can understand my position.